# Getting java.lang.IllegalAccessError when Notification is received

Tags: android, firebase, dependencies, firebase-cloud-messaging, onesignal

I am getting this Error when a notification is received from OneSignal:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Illegal class access: 'com.google.firebase.messaging.zze' attempting to access 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzat' (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.messaging.zze' appears in /data/app/com.foodhat.app-waMACkXIseLBt87YFrcPWQ==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.zze.onBind(com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@@19.0.1:11)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindService(ActivityThread.java:4221)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:269)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2031)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7857)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
```

Here is my `build.gradle` (Module:app):

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0' //for bundleOf()
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0' //1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    //Android Architecture Components
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.2.0'

    //OkHttp OAuth2 client
    implementation 'ca.mimic:oauth2library:2.4.2'

    //Anko
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:0.10.8"

    //Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'

    //Firebase Dynmaic Links
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links-ktx:19.1.0'

    //Crashlytics
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'

    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

    //Google Maps
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'

    //OneSignal
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.9'

    //Picasso
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    //GIF ImageView
    //implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.15'

    //Jackson
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.8"

    //Volley
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

    //SegmentedButton
    implementation 'com.github.ceryle:SegmentedButton:v2.0.2'

    //EasyValidation
    implementation "com.wajahatkarim3.easyvalidation:easyvalidation-core:1.0.1"

    //QuickPermissions-Kotlin
    implementation 'com.github.quickpermissions:quickpermissions-kotlin:0.4.0'
```

It is very weird because I have no firebase-core dependency included (I read somewhere that the firebase-core is no more used so we should not include it).

- Firebase-auth is not the latest version here, the last one would be 19.3.1
- firebase-analytics is not the latest version here, the last one would be 17.4.2

But even when updating these dependencies the error occours.

Any ideas why this occours?